# How to backcalculate P value from r and n

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, p-value

So I have r and n values for a number of correlations. And I'd like to back-calculate the p value. I know there are tonnes of calculators online to do this easily, but I am looking for a way to do it in R.

Want to get p values given r and n for simple correlations.

- Input `r = -0.088227` , `n = 237`
- Output `p = 0.175832`

Comment: Input r = -0.088227  , n = 237

Output p =0.175832

As for online calculators:

https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=44
https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/pearsondistribution.aspx
https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/PValue1.cfm
https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/r-to-p.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess with correlation you mean a Pearson Product-Moment Correlation. If so you can write a function for this

```
rn_to_p <- function(rval, n){
  # calculate r to t
  tval <- rval/(sqrt((1-rval**2)/(n-2)))
  # look up p value for t
  pval <- 2*pt(abs(tval), n-2, lower=FALSE)
  return(pval)}
```

Here is an example

```
# make it reproducible
set.seed(1)
# generate data
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), ncol= 2))

# apply the function
rn_to_p(rval=cor.test(df$X1, df$X2)$estimate, n= nrow(df))
# 0.9921663
# see results of cor.test
cor.test(df$X1, df$X2)
# ... p-value = 0.9922 ...
```

For your example...

```
> rn_to_p(-0.088227, n = 237)
[1] 0.1758329
```

The formula to transform the Pearson's coefficient r to a t value can be found [here](http://vassarstats.net/tabs_r.html), for example.

Comment: Instead of `if`, you can use `abs(tval)`.